# Not able to pass Props to Component - Inconsistent Behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js

I have a React.js and Next.js app where I need to pass the User object to all the pages. I then plan to pass this User component to Head component so that I can show different navigation based on user role. This is what I have so far:

This is _App.js where I check if user token exists. If it exists, I verify it by calling an API and then I assign the result to pageProps. This pageProps is then passed to other components.

```js
import '../styles/global.css'
import CustomTheme from '../styles/custom-theme';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { getToken, setUserSession } from '../utils/common';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  useEffect(()=>{
    const token = getToken();
    console.log(token)
    if (!token){
      console.log('no token')
      return;
    }

    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'x-access-token': token },
      //body: token
    };

    fetch("http://localhost:3600/auth/verifyToken", requestOptions)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
          (result) => {
            pageProps.user = JSON.stringify(result);
            console.log('verifyToken response 2 : ' + JSON.stringify(result))
      })
  },[])

  console.log(pageProps)
  return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={CustomTheme}>
    {/* <Component {...pageProps} /> */}
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Then, in my waiting-room.js page, I try to get hold of this prop and print it:

```
export default function WaitingRoom(pageProps) {
const classes = useStyles();
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('yes');
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
const [childName, setChildName] = useState(null);
const [demoData, setDemoData] = useState(null);
const [counterTime, setCounterTime] = useState(null);
const [disableJoin, setDisableJoin] = useState(true);
const [classOver, setClassOver] = useState(false);
const [demoBooked, setDemoBooked] = useState(false);

// Note: the empty deps array [] means
// this useEffect will run once
// similar to componentDidMount()
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("pageProps : " + JSON.stringify(pageProps.user))
})
}
```

First time page load, everything is fine. All console.log statements print values as expected. But when I click on browser refresh button, I see pageProps as undefined. And then when I again make some changes on the page and save it, it starts working till I again hit browser refresh. Is it something to do with server side rendering?

Edit post @Siddhart's answer:

[image: Console.log after server refresh]

[image: React Dev tools component view after server refresh]

[image: Console.log after Browser refresh. pageProps are gone]

[image: React Dev tools component view after Browser refresh. pageProps are there.]

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing the weird behavior because you're mutating the original `pageProps` object.

**Reason why you're not seeing the `pageProps` changes**

`WaitingRoom` isn't aware of any change because reference to the `pageProps` remain same.

**Reason why you see the `pageProps` changes**

Probably `MyApp` component re-renders due to some prop change which in turn causes the re-render of child component i.e. `WaitingFroom`

What you need to do is, update state when `pageProps` changes so that component re-renders with updated props.

```
import '../styles/global.css'
import CustomTheme from '../styles/custom-theme';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { getToken, setUserSession } from '../utils/common';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
 
  const [updatedProps, setUpdatedProps] = useState(pageProps);
  
  // If pageProps change over time
  useEffect(() => {
     setUpdatedProps(prevUpdatedProps => ({
      ...prevUpdatedProps,
      ...pageProps
    }));
  }, [pageProps])


  useEffect(()=>{
    const token = getToken();
    console.log(token)
    if (!token){
      console.log('no token')
      return;
    }

    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'x-access-token': token },
      //body: token
    };

    fetch("http://localhost:3600/auth/verifyToken", requestOptions)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
          (result) => {
            pageProps.user = JSON.stringify(result);
            setUpdatedProps({...updatedProps, user: JSON.stringify(result)});
            console.log('verifyToken response 2 : ' + JSON.stringify(result))
      })
  },[])

  return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={CustomTheme}>
    <Component {...updatedProps} />
  </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: Thanks @Siddharth. This partly fixed my problem. Now, when I check using React Dev Tools, I always see correct value of pageProps. But, when I am doing Console.log("pageProps : " + pageProp) in my waitingRoom page, value still comes as undefined or blank when I do a browser refresh. I'm attaching screen shots in the original post showing this. Also to note is, Console.log of waitingRoom page is printed before console.log of _App.